# Delete AlertDialog after 6 minutes in case the user does not interact with the app

Tags: android

I am implementing an app which run in the Background. Therefor I  am using Service class. The AlertDialog.Build wroks well but I want to add additionally functionality to Dialog window to delete  it after 6 minutes  in the case the user does not interact with the window.

```
    private void stop_popup(final ArrayList<Integer> routeList) {

        int routeListSize = routeList.size();
// to Show the Dialog once.
        flag = false;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                flag = true;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000 * 60);

        if (routeListSize > 0) {

            String[] charSequence = new String[routeList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
                charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setTitle("Has this route arrived the stop? ");

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                boolean isChecked) {



                                route_number = routeList.get(which);


                            }

                        }
                    });

            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            // To launch the dialog window from the TrackingService class.
            alert.getWindow().setType(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A. Remove the flag.
2. Move the handler to the bottom of the method.
3. Make the *alert* final.
4. At the handler's runnable check *alert!=null&&alert.isShowing()* and then call alert.dismiss();

Comment: I Need the flag to set the Dialog window once and not each time every 10 seconds with the Response from the server.

Comment: Then keep it. did u try the other steps?

Comment: Then I dont need to move the handler to the bottom of the method? do you mean after alert.show()?

Comment: You need to move the handler to the bottom becuase he need to holds a reference to **alert** and it doesnt exist early in the mtehod